# Calculate total length of linear growth equation

Tags: geometric-series

Alright, I'm having a really difficult time putting the correct mathematical terms on the problem I'm trying to deal with (which is probably why I can't find an answer), so bear with me.*

```
0
|-->

*----*----*-------*------------*
     |    |       |            |
     x0   x1      x2           x3
```

I have a function that linearly increases the distance between successive points based on the position of the previous point.

$$x_{i+1} = x_i + \phi x_i$$

$x_0$ and $x_1$ are given, but $x_0 \neq 0$ . $\phi$ is the linear growth rate

How do I calculate the value of an arbitrary $x_i$ without calculating the value of all the other points?

PS, I'm really not sure what the appropriate tag is because there isn't a "growth" tag. Power series is just a guess as to what the answer might be.

*From the [selected answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2902941/486538) the sequence described is a [geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)

Comment: Try writing out the values of $x_1, x_2, x_ 3$ and $x_4$ -- you should see a pattern pretty quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x_{i+1}=(\phi+1) x_i$, you have a geometric sequence:

$$x_1=(\phi+1) x_0$$

$$x_2=(\phi+1) x_1=(\phi+1)(\phi+1) x_0=(\phi+1)^2 x_0$$

In general,

$$x_n=x_0(1+\phi)^n$$

Comment: Yes, but that still requires a loop to solve for an arbitrary value $x_i$. Is there not a single mathematical function that will do that?

Comment: $\phi$ is a constant.

Comment: Oh I see, will edit in the solution.